# Find and replace files accross Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, find-and-replace

Is there a way in Windows to find and replace all files?

Could PowerShell do this?

I have a .dll file that I have a bunch of and would like to update them all with one click.

EDIT:
I would like to be able to replace file1.dll with another file1.dll and rename the old one to file1.dll.original

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if made your objectives more clear and included a more verbose description.  As it stands now this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  To answer what you have made somewhat clear, yes, Powershell can find and replace files

Comment: If you have enough copies of the same DLL that you need to do a search and replace on them then you are doing it wrong. After the second or third copy you should have moved it to a common location and pointed the programs at that single copy.

Answer (score 4):

From what I *think* you're trying to do, this should solve your problem (using Powershell)

```
$oldLocation = "C:\users\user\FilesToBeCopied"
$newLocation = "C:\users\user\FilesThatNeedToBeOriginal"
cd $newLocation
dir | % {  $name = $_.Name + ".original"; ren $_ $name; }
copy $oldLocation\* $newLocation
```

Comment: This is your answer please be sure to give him credit!

Answer (score 0):

reserv.cmd:

```
SET in=I:\work directory
SET out=I:\source directory
SET cmSet=for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B

%cmSet% "%in%\*.dll"') do ren "%in%\%%A" "%%~A.original"
%cmSet% "%out%\*.dll"') do xcopy /I /S /E /H /Q /-Y /Z "%out%\%%A" "%in%\"
```